# Magento 2 Fatal Error :: Maximum Functions Nesting Level of '100' reached

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, xdebug

I got this error after installing Magento 2 on my local machine over wamp software:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of ’100′ reached, aborting! in \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config.php on line 69

Comment: You can self answer your question but that still requires your question and it's answer to be inline with the standards needed on this site.

Comment: Summarize the link in an answer, please. Links have a habit of dying and the information becomes useless. Just had this happen over on Magento Commerce of all places. The answer to the issue was a comment in a bugfix request. The bugfix database was upgraded and as usual over there all older references deleted. No more resolution to the issue.

Answer (score 26):

You can still use xdebug in Magento 2, but it will require modifying [the default `max_nesting_level` value of 100 that xdebug uses](http://xdebug.org/docs/basic#max_nesting_level).

Open up the `php.ini` file being used by your server and update or add the following config, depending on if it already exists in your file:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

This works for me, but if you still see the error you can try doubling the value again.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me too, Have configured the same in PHP.ini and it worked.

Comment: Hey, i updated from 200 to 300, xdebug.max_nesting_level = 300 . but still i get the same error

Comment: Hey, i updated from 200 to 300, xdebug.max_nesting_level = 300 . but still i get the same error

Comment: Would suggest keep doubling and see if it goes away (200, 400, 800, 1600). If not then open an issue with full trace to the Magento GitHub

Comment: it helped .......put value 1000